# Writing { and } to a file with LaTeX

Tags: symbols, verbatim, auxiliary-files, write

How can the special characters `{` and `}` be written literally to an external file in LaTeX, without being balanced?

Obviously the following does not work:

```
 \immediate\write\my@outfile{{}
 \immediate\write\my@outfile{}}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Writing balanced braces doesn't require anything special, as the following transcript of an interactive TeX session shows:

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
**\relax
*\newwrite\mywr
*\immediate\openout\mywr=temp.dat
*\immediate\write\mywr{{}}
*\bye
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
$ cat temp.dat
{}
```

If you want to write unbalanced braces you can do with

```
\begingroup
\catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12
\gdef\wbgroup<{>
\gdef\wegroup<}>
\endgroup

\newwrite\mywr
\immediate\openout\mywr=temp.dat

\immediate\write\mywr{\wbgroup}
\immediate\write\mywr{\wegroup}

\bye
```

that is, using `\wbgroup` and `\wegroup` for writing open and close brace respectively. The contents of `temp.dat` will be

```
{
}
```

Notice that LaTeX already has equivalents of `\wbgroup` and `\wegroup` that are called `\@charlb` and `\@charrb`, which actually expand to category code 11 characters.

Alternative definitions for `\wbgroup` and `\wegroup` that expand to category code 12 characters are

```
\begingroup\lccode`?=`\{ \lccode`!=`\}
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\wbgroup{?}\def\wegroup{!}}
```

or

```
\edef\wbgroup{\iftrue\string{\else}\fi}
\edef\wegroup{\iffalse{\else\string}\fi}
```

Answer (score 14):

In order to write unbalanced braces you should use macros which hold them as  verbatim characters instead. These will be expanded when written to the file. LaTeX2e defines `\@charlb` (left brace) and `\@charrb` (right brace) which require `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother` of course. You can find these listed in `source2e` or better `macros2e`.

```
\immediate\write\my@outfile{\@charlb}
\immediate\write\my@outfile{\@charrb}
```

You can also define you own macro easily with `\Verbdef` from my `newverbs` package (not to be confused with `\verbdef` from the `verbdef` package). Macros define this way are usable to be written to an external file (in contrast to `\verbdef` which macros them typsetable).

```
\usepackage{newverbs}
\Verbdef\leftbrace|{|
\Verbdef\rightbrace|}|
% ...

\immediate\write\myoutfile{\leftbrace}
\immediate\write\myoutfile{\rightbrace}
```

Comment: The \Verbdef-Methode doesn't seem to work any more: "\protected" is inserted into the output (it worked well with TL2020 but not after I switched to TL2021). Edit: \@charlb also doesn't seem to work. egreg's anwers works well.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you want to do, you can try escaping it

```
\newwrite\temp
\immediate\openout\temp=temp.dat
\immediate\write\temp{\}}
\bye
```

This will write `\delimiter "5267309` in the `temp.dat` file or you can write `\string\}`, which will write  `\}` in the file.