# How to output a curly brace, which is interpreted only as a character?

Tags: braces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing { and } to a file with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47452/writing-and-to-a-file-with-latex)

I want to output a curly brace, which will not be interpreted as a group delimiter. My attempt does not work:

```
\def\aa{\string}}
```

I want that calling `\aa` will output `}`.

**EDIT** As egreg mentionned, my aim is to have a brace that can be later on written into a file. The proposed solution `\{` outputs correctly a brace, but attempting to write it in a file fails :

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile="nico.txt"
\def\aa{\{}
\immediate\write\tempfile{blabla blabla \a blabla}
```

Comment: You probably should clarify the purpose of this question, which I believe is *not* printing a brace, but outputting it when writing a file.

Comment: Have you tried \def\aa{\}} ?

Comment: @egreg : you read in my mind ... ;)

Comment: @nicolasroy Please look at the linked probable duplicate.

Comment: @egreg : yes, it is exactly a duplicate. Can i close the question officially ?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `\}`

This is probably a duplicate question.

Edit: I should also say; putting a backslash `\` before nearly any special character in TeX will cause LaTeX to treat it as non-special (and vice versa).

You can either use `\}` directly, or just put it inside the macro definition:

```
\def\aa{\}}
```

Comment: The I should say part is wrong. Try `\texttt{\{}`. Compare that to `\verb|{|`

Comment: @Clément `\verb` is a special command, naturally the rules do not apply to it.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant.  I meant that, unless you use use T1 with inputenc, you won't get a monospace `{` by using `\{` inside of `\texttt`.

Comment: I see... Well feel free to update the answer to your liking, it's not as though it's relevant to the asker's updated question and it's a dupe anyhow.