# Catcode change doesn't take effect

Tags: catcodes

Why does the following TeX manuscript result in an error upon compilation with TeX Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017)?

```
\catcode`}=12}\bye
```

The error is:

```
! Too many }'s.
<recently read> }

l.1 \catcode`}=12}
                  \bye
```

What I expected to happen was that the compilation would complete successfully and the resulting `dvi` file would consist of the single character **}** (right brace).

---

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47452) but different in that I'm not interested in how to print out a right brace, but rather in why the described method for doing so fails.

Comment: I think you need a space after the number ``\catcode`}=12 }\bye``

Comment: @clemens: Adding a space after the number indeed allows the compilation to complete, however the output is not a right brace but rather what looks like a quotation mark ".

Comment: @EvanAad you get the character in position 125 of the current font which is not always the shape `}` try it with `\tt`

Comment: computer modern roman, the default font in plain tex does not have a character with shape `}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input fails for the reasons explained in your last question, you need

```
\catcode`}=12 }\bye
```

so the number is finished before `}` is tokenised.

Comment: Adding a space after the number indeed allows the compilation to complete, however the output is not a right brace but rather what looks like a quotation mark ".

Comment: @EvanAad you get the character from position 125 in the current font. Try `\tt` in front if you want a font with an encoding closer to ascii.

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't TeX realize that the number has ended upon encountering the second **}**? If, for instance, I change the original manuscript by adding the **@** character, whose catcode is 12, between the number and the right brace, the manuscript compiles successfully and the output is `@}` (or rather `@"` for the reason mentioned in your comment).

Comment: Nevermind, I think I know the answer. The reason is that it is the TeX "stomach" that decides when the number ends, but the stomach only "sees" tokens, so in order to "see" the right brace it has to be tokenized by the "mouth", which tokenizes it with the original catcode 2, because the catcode won't change until the "stomach" has finished processing the `\catcode` command.

Answer (score 5):

When TeX is looking for a number it continues scanning tokens and expanding them until finding an unexpandable token that cannot be interpreted as a digit (in the already set radix, default decimal).

If this unexpandable token is a space token, it gets ignored (only one, though).

This means that with

```
\catcode`}=12}
```

the assignment has not yet been performed when the number is complete, and `}` has been tokenized with its current category code, that is, 2.

*Always* finish your constants with a space. Quoting the TeXbook:

> For best results, *always put a blank space after a numeric constant*;
>   this blank space tells TeX that the constant is complete, and
>   such a space will never “get through” to the output.  In fact, when you
>   don't have a blank space after a constant, TeX actually has to do
>   more work, because each constant continues until a non-digit has been
>   read; if this non-digit is not a space, TeX takes the token you did have
>   and backs it up, ready to be read again. (On the other hand, the author
>   often omits the space when a constant is immediately followed by some
>   other character, because extra spaces do look funny in the file;
>   aesthetics are more important than efficiency.)

This is different from other assignments:

```
\def\foo{1} % just for an example
\chardef\foo=12\foo
```

will not be equivalent to `\chardef\foo=121`, because in these cases TeX temporarily sets `\foo` as equivalent to `\relax`, until it can perform the assignment. So the second `\foo` stops the search for digits and no expansion of `\foo` will be done. On the other hand

```
\chardef\foo=12 \foo
```

works the same and is clearer.

Comment: Thanks. A couple comments. 1. You ended your answer with "works the same and is clearer." Works the same as what? Not the same as the 1st example. 2. The 1st example can also be explained by the following sentence from the TeXbook (1st paragraph on p. 207): "TeX requires the tokens in a numerical constant to be digits, after macro expansion". The last occurrence of `\foo` is still a macro as long as the TeX "stomach" has not finished "digesting" the `\chardef`, and therefore this macro is expanded to `1` and the "stomach" "sees" this `1` as the third digit.

Comment: @EvanAad “works the same” as `\chardef\foo=12\foo`. Your final analysis is wrong: when TeX scans `\chardef\foo` it temporarily makes `\foo` equivalent to `\relax`, as explained in the text.