# The laws of expansion (\chardef\foo=<number>\foo)

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

- **Fact** The file-name of the default font for a pdfTeX-compiled LaTeX document on my system is `cmr10`. (How do I know? `\fontname\font`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376354/21685).)
- **Fact** The font defined in the file `cmr10` has a glyph of the Greek capital letter lambda at code point 3, and a glyph of the mathematical symbol for the empty set at code point 31. (How do I know? `\fonttable{cmr10}`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376320/21685).)

Consider the following (La)TeX manuscript, inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376262/21685).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{1}
\chardef\foo=3\foo
\end{document}
```

Compiling the manuscript with pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) results in a pdf file, whose body consists of a single letter: a Greek capital letter lambda.

This goes contrary to my expectations that the body of the pdf would consist of the mathematical symbol for the empty set.

What did I base my expectation on? On Donald Knuth's *The TeXbook*, 20th revised printing (Addison-Wesley 1991), where, on p. 215, he lists *all* the cases when expandable tokens are *not* expanded.

If you peruse the list you will notice that in the case of `\chardef`, macro expansion is inhibited only in the stage of reading the control sequence to be defined. (Compare this to, say, `\def`, where expansion is additionally inhibited while absorbing the parameter text and the replacement text.)

Returning to the manuscript I started with, it can be deduced from Knuth's list of non-expandables that the second occurrence of control sequence `\foo` in the line

```
\chardef\foo=3\foo
```

*is* expanded. Note that at the time this expansion takes place the `\chardef` definition is still processing, so the control sequence `\foo` must still be defined as a macro with the replacement text `1`. Hence this line redefines `\foo` to be `\char31`.

Interestingly, the following, similar manuscript produces the expected result (i.e. the empty-set symbol).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{1}
\chardef\bar=3\foo\bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is that `\chardef\<name>` turns `\<name>` temporarily into `\relax`. We can see this with `\tracingall`:

```
\def\foo{1}
\tracingall
\chardef\bar=3\foo\bar
```

yields

```
{\chardef}
{changing \bar=macro:->\mathaccent "7016\relax }
{into \bar=\relax}

\foo ->1
{changing \bar=\relax}
{into \bar=\char"1F}
{\char"1F}
```

whereas with

```
\def\foo{1}
\tracingall
\chardef\foo=3\foo
```

we get

```
{\chardef}
{changing \foo=macro:->1}
{into \foo=\relax}
{changing \foo=\relax}
{into \foo=\char"3}
{\char"3}
```

So we get the outcomes you observe, not because of `\chardef` failing to expand material but because of the nature of the material *at the point it is examined*.

Knuth says:

```
\TeX\ takes precautions so that constructions like `|\chardef\cs=10\cs|' and
`|\font\cs=name\cs|' won't expand the second |\cs| until
the assignments are done.
```

(Chapter 24, 'Summary of Vertical Mode, page 278).

Comment: I'd _strongly_ recommend terminating the scanner here with an explicit space or `\relax`, not relying on what can be tricky-to-follow (though documented) behaviour of other tokens.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the TeXbook (p. 278)

> TeX takes precautions so that constructions like ‘`\chardef\cs=10\cs|`’ and ‘`\font\cs=name\cs`’ won’t expand the second `\cs` until
>   the assignments are done.

Those precautions are covered in module 1224 of `tex.web`:

[image]

A ‘shorthand def’ is one of the definition-like primitives described in the module.

Knuth warns that the book doesn't always tell the complete truth.