# Primitives that share \chardef's peculiar behavior

Tags: tex-core, expansion

The `\chardef` primitive exhibits a peculiar behavior: the command

```
\chardef\controlSequence=<number>
```

behaves as though it were preceded by

```
\let\controlSequence=\relax
```

(see the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376429/21685)).

Is there any other similar TeX primitive, `\p`, that behaves as though some tokens have been (re)defined just before `\p` is expanded/executed?

* I'm looking for an exhaustive list, but a partial list is also welcome.

Comment: The list could be easily inferred from the quotation of `tex.web` at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376435/4427

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\mathchardef` for math characters behave in a similar way.

```
\tracingall
\chardef\foo=123
\mathchardef\baz=123
\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

The `.log` contains:

```
{changing \foo=undefined}
{into \foo=\relax}
```

and

```
{changing \baz=undefined}
{into \baz=\relax}
```

Other commands:

```
\countdef
\dimendef
\skipdef
\muskipdef
\toksdef
```

The list comes from the source code `tex.web` (keyword `shorthand_def`):

> ```
> @ A \.{\\chardef} creates a control sequence whose |cmd| is |char_given|;
> a \.{\\mathchardef} creates a control sequence whose |cmd| is |math_given|;
> and the corresponding |chr| is the character code or math code. A \.{\\countdef}
> or \.{\\dimendef} or \.{\\skipdef} or \.{\\muskipdef} creates a control
> sequence whose |cmd| is |assign_int| or \dots\ or |assign_mu_glue|, and the
> corresponding |chr| is the |eqtb| location of the internal register in question.
>
> @d char_def_code=0 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\chardef}}
> @d math_char_def_code=1 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\mathchardef}}
> @d count_def_code=2 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\countdef}}
> @d dimen_def_code=3 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\dimendef}}
> @d skip_def_code=4 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\skipdef}}
> @d mu_skip_def_code=5 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\muskipdef}}
> @d toks_def_code=6 {|shorthand_def| for \.{\\toksdef}}
>
> @<Put each...@>=
> primitive("chardef",shorthand_def,char_def_code);@/
> @!@:char_def_}{\.{\\chardef} primitive@>
> primitive("mathchardef",shorthand_def,math_char_def_code);@/
> @!@:math_char_def_}{\.{\\mathchardef} primitive@>
> primitive("countdef",shorthand_def,count_def_code);@/
> @!@:count_def_}{\.{\\countdef} primitive@>
> primitive("dimendef",shorthand_def,dimen_def_code);@/
> @!@:dimen_def_}{\.{\\dimendef} primitive@>
> primitive("skipdef",shorthand_def,skip_def_code);@/
> @!@:skip_def_}{\.{\\skipdef} primitive@>
> primitive("muskipdef",shorthand_def,mu_skip_def_code);@/
> @!@:mu_skip_def_}{\.{\\muskipdef} primitive@>
> primitive("toksdef",shorthand_def,toks_def_code);@/
> @!@:toks_def_}{\.{\\toksdef} primitive@>
>
> @ @<Cases of |print_cmd_chr|...@>=
> shorthand_def: case chr_code of
>   char_def_code: print_esc("chardef");
>   math_char_def_code: print_esc("mathchardef");
>   count_def_code: print_esc("countdef");
>   dimen_def_code: print_esc("dimendef");
>   skip_def_code: print_esc("skipdef");
>   mu_skip_def_code: print_esc("muskipdef");
>   othercases print_esc("toksdef")
>   endcases;
> char_given: begin print_esc("char"); print_hex(chr_code);
>   end;
> math_given: begin print_esc("mathchar"); print_hex(chr_code);
>   end;
>
> @ We temporarily define |p| to be |relax|, so that an occurrence of |p|
> while scanning the definition will simply stop the scanning instead of
> producing an ``undefined control sequence'' error or expanding the
> previous meaning.  This allows, for instance, `\.{\\chardef\\foo=123\\foo}'.
>
> @<Assignments@>=
> shorthand_def: begin n:=cur_chr; get_r_token; p:=cur_cs; define(p,relax,256);
>   scan_optional_equals;
>   case n of
>   char_def_code: begin scan_char_num; define(p,char_given,cur_val);
>     end;
>   math_char_def_code: begin scan_fifteen_bit_int; define(p,math_given,cur_val);
>     end;
>   othercases begin scan_eight_bit_int;
>     case n of
>     count_def_code: define(p,assign_int,count_base+cur_val);
>     dimen_def_code: define(p,assign_dimen,scaled_base+cur_val);
>     skip_def_code: define(p,assign_glue,skip_base+cur_val);
>     mu_skip_def_code: define(p,assign_mu_glue,mu_skip_base+cur_val);
>     toks_def_code: define(p,assign_toks,toks_base+cur_val);
>     end; {there are no other cases}
>     end
>   endcases;
>   end;
> ```

There is another, but different case, where a control sequence gets assigned to `\relax`: If the command sequence constructed by `\csname ...\endcsname` is undefined, then it is assigned to `\relax`.

The case `\font`, see Joseph Wright's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376621/primitives-that-share-chardefs-peculiar-behavior/376623?noredirect=1#comment932534_376623):

```
\tracingall
\font\foo\foo
\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

From the `.log`, `\foo` is temporarily defined to an non-expandable command:

```
{changing \foo=undefined}
{into \foo=select font nullfont}
```

Comment: Is this an exhaustive list?

Comment: @EvanAad I have added all cases, where macro `define` is used with meaning `\relax` in the source `tex.web`.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `\font` is similar (though not identical, goes _via_ `\nullfont`).

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, worth noting! If you have any more like this, please don't hold back...

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: you mean to say that the expression `\csname name\endcsname` behaves as though it were immediately *followed* by `\let\name=\relax`, correct?

Comment: @EvanAad No, `\name` will have the meaning `\relax` instead of undefined only if it was undefined before.

Comment: I've done some experimenting, and I think that the `\csname ... \endcsname` construct is different than the others, including `\font`, in that `\csname foo\endcsname` does not behave as though it were *preceded* by `\let\foo=\relax`.

Comment: Indeed, consider the following TeX manuscript: `\def\nick{nack} \expandafter\def\csname nick\nick\endcsname{pattiwhack} \nicknack \bye`. If the `\csname ... \endcsname` construct behaved like `\chardef`, `tex` would throw an error, because the control sequence `\nicknack` would be undefined. However the manuscript compiles successfully, and outputs `pattiwhack`.

Answer (score 5):

The full list can be inferred from the quotation of `tex.web` I already pointed to in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376435/4427

[image]

There's also the case of `\font` that's slightly different in that the control sequence is assigned `\nullfont` instead of `\relax`.